# How to extract specific portion of text from file in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to extract a specific portion from a text.
For example, I have this text:

```
"*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum*",
```

I would like to extract the content from "*Duis aute*" to the start a new line ("*nulla pariatur*").
How could I do this in Python? Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: So have you tried anything? This is a pretty simple question, with a few different answers depending on how you intend to use it.

Comment: By "new line" here, do you mean a period `.` or are there actually `\n` newline characters in your text?

Comment: @Mortz Thanks to your answer, I mean \n

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry for poor English.**

You can use this.

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f: # open file and get the data.
    data = f.read()

s_index = data.index('Duis aute') # get the starting index of text.
e_index = data.index('.',s_index) # get the end index of text here I also pass s_index as the parameter because I want the index of the dot after the starting index.

text = data[s_index:e_index]
print(text)
```

Output

```
Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
```

If you want to end the text by `\n` Then use this one

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = ''.join(data)

# here try and except for because if the substring not in the string then it will throw an error.
try:
    s_index = data.index('Duis aute')
    e_index = data.index('\n',s_index)
except:
    print('Value Not Found.')
else:
    text = data[s_index:e_index]
    print(text)
```

#### Testing

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = ''.join(data)

# here try and except for because if the substring not in the string then it will throw an error.
try:
    s_index = data.index('ipsum dolor')
    e_index = data.index('\n',s_index)
except:
    print('Value Not Found.')
else:
    text = data[s_index:e_index]
    print(text)
```

output

```
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = ''.join(data)

# here try and except for because if the substring not in the string then it will throw an error.
try:
    s_index = data.index('Ut enim ad minim')
    e_index = data.index('\n',s_index)
except:
    print('Value Not Found.')
else:
    text = data[s_index:e_index]
    print(text)
```

output

```
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
```

And If you need only one word after the given word then use this.

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = ''.join(data)

# here try and except for because if the substring not in the string then it will throw an error.
try:
    s_index = data.index('Lorem')
    e_index = data.index(' ',s_index+len('Lorem')+1)
except:
    print('Value Not Found.')
else:
    text = data[s_index:e_index]
    print(text)
```

output

```
Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. =)

Comment: What if I wanted to extract from "Duis aute" except it?

Comment: Then just change `s_index = data.index(Anything)`

Comment: I tried to change, but it still extracts the entered phrase. The problem is that I don't know a priori what is after the sentence to start from

Comment: @GiorgioGiò Check my answer.

Comment: @GiorgioGiò I edit my code with some other value

Comment: I tried also your last solution. But I would like to exclude the words entered in *s_index = data.index(Anything)* from the result

Comment: `Anything` Means I want you to add some value here like `Ut enim ad minim`.

Comment: Yes I know, but I only need the one after the entered word in *s_index = data.index(Anything)*. In this way, the entered word is also extracted to me. 
Anyway thank you for taking your time for this =)

Comment: If you need only one word  then  Change this `e_index = data.index(' ',s_index) `

Comment: Nono, I need content starting after "Duis aute" to "nulla pariatur"

Comment: @GiorgioGiò Then use my first or second solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will certainly use one of the two solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract a particular "sentence" - then one way could be to split on the sentence separator (`\n` for example)

```py
sentences = s.split('\n')
```

If you have multiple delimiters for a sentence - you can use the `re` module -

```py
import re
sentences = re.split(r'\.|\n', s)
```

You can then extract the matches from `sentences`  -

```py
required = '\n'.join(_ for _ in sentences if _.strip().startswith('Duis aute'))
```

Of course, you can combine all of this into a single liner -

```py
'\n'.join(_ for _ in s.split('.') if _.strip().startswith('Duis aute'))
```